# Plot lines in ggplot from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, plot, ggplot2

I have a list of data.frames:

```
samplelist = list(a = data.frame(x = c(1:10), y=rnorm(10),
                 b= data.frame(x=c(5:10), y = rnorm(5),
                 c = data.frame(x=c(2:12), y=rnorm(10))
```

I'd like to structure a `ggplot` of the following format:

```
ggplot()+ 
    geom_line(data=samplelist[[1]], aes(x,y))+
    geom_line(data=samplelist[[2]], aes(x,y))+
    geom_line(data=samplelist[[3]], aes(x,y))
```

But that isn't super automated. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, your `samplelist` code has a few errrors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ggplot` works most efficiently with data in "long" format. In this case, that means stacking your three data frames into a single data frame with an extra column added to identify the source data frame. In that format, you need only one call to `geom_line`, while the new column identifying the source data frame can be used as a colour aesthetic, resulting in a different line for each source data frame. The `dplyr` function `bind_rows` allows you to stack the data frames on the fly, within the call to `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

samplelist = list(a = data.frame(x=c(1:10), y=rnorm(10)),
                  b = data.frame(x=c(5:10), y=rnorm(6)),
                  c = data.frame(x=c(2:12), y=rnorm(11)))

ggplot(bind_rows(samplelist, .id="df"), aes(x, y, colour=df)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I assumed above that you would want each line to be a different color and for there to be a legend showing the color mapping. However, if, for some reason, you just want three black lines and no legend, just change `colour=df` to `group=df`.

Comment: I'm receiving Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames

Answer (score 3):

This will work -

```
library(ggplot2)
samplelist <- list(a = data.frame(x = c(1:10), y=rnorm(10)),
                  b = data.frame(x=c(5:10), y = rnorm(6)),
                  c = data.frame(x=c(2:12), y=rnorm(11)))

p <- ggplot()
for (i in 1:3) p <- p + geom_line(data=samplelist[[i]], aes(x,y))
p
```

Comment: your suggestion of using `i` in `aes()` will fail

Comment: Good point, they would all need to be in the same df to use that. edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use lapply.

```
library(ggplot2)

samplelist = list(a = data.frame(x = c(1:10), y=rnorm(10)),
                  b= data.frame(x=c(5:10), y = rnorm(6)),
                  c = data.frame(x=c(2:12), y=rnorm(11)))

p <- ggplot()

plot <- function(df){
    p <<- p + geom_line(data=df, aes(x,y))
}

lapply(samplelist, plot)

p
```

Comment: using `<<-` is often not the best strategy in R (typically because one prefers to avoid side-effects in non-local environments); I think `Reduce()` is more idiomatic here.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce is another option to add things iteratively,

```
library(ggplot2)

samplelist = list(a = data.frame(x = c(1:10), y=rnorm(10)),
                  b= data.frame(x=c(5:10), y = rnorm(6)),
                  c = data.frame(x=c(2:12), y=rnorm(11)))

pl <- Reduce(f = function(p, d) p + geom_line(data=d, aes(x,y)), 
             x = samplelist, init = ggplot(), accumulate = TRUE)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = pl)
```

[image]